# Calculate common difference and the first term

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The sum of the 6th and 10th terms of an arithmetic sequence is 24. The 11th term exceeds the 8th term by 8 . Calculate
a) the common difference
b) the first term

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Do you know the general form of an arithmetic sequence? If so, do you know how to calculate the 6th and 10th term?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the common distance be $d$ and the sequence be $a_i$. Then $$a_6+a_{10}=24$$ but $a_{10}=a_6+4d$ and $a_6=a_0+6d$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I will try , but can u please explain for me why it turn  to a10=a6+4d ?

Comment: Because $a_{10}$ is four $d$s away from $a_6$ and you need two equations in $d$ and $a_0$.

Comment: Im not sure , I need more explaination , because   I still in learning progress .

Comment: Okay i just understand that part .. I will try to continue it :) :)